# Instagram Api with package python-instagram change scope

Tags: python, api, scope, instagram, instagram-api

I used `python-instagram` and I want to change the scope but with package `python-instagram` I don't know how? I saw the code but I don't find where we can change it?

I need to change scope for add "relationship" scope because I have an error:

> ERROR: (400) OAuthPermissionsException-This request requires scope=relationships, but this access token is not authorized with this
>   scope. The user must re-authorize your application with
>   scope=relationships to be granted write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

When you authorize your app and get the access token, you need to declare the scope. You can authorize your app/get token by creating a URL like this:

```
https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize?scope={relationships comments likes}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}&response_type=code&client_id={client id}
```

just pass in the scope in the scope parameter.

Comment: I got this error instead `{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}`
This was the link I used: `https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize?scope=public_content&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&client_id={client id}`
I can guarantee the client id is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for permission from Instagram to use those scopes: relationships, comments and likes. Here is the link to the form would have to fill in order to submit your request for permission.

https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

Hope you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After 17 November 2015, a lot of permission is very restricted in Instagram. You have to submit a request for permission to get that scope. Please refer to this links:

- https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/
- https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/